# Hibernate - How to control generator class used when running hbm2hbmxml

Tags: nhibernate

My hbm2hbmxml task is generating ids such as below

```
    <id name="id" type="long">
        <column name="id" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
```

I'd like them all to be "native".  Can I configure the Hibernate reverse engineering to do this?

Thx,
Fred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can create a custom ReverseEngineeringStrategy by extending DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy, override

@Override
 public String getTableIdentifierStrategyName(final TableIdentifier tableIdentifier) {

// Always use native identifier strategy

return "native";
 }

and have HibernateToolTask refer to this class:
reversestrategy="com.foo.MyReverseEngineeringStrategy"

Cheers, Kjeld